# Revert commit on branch A which is going to be merged to B later. Commit should stay on B

Tags: git, git-merge, gitversion

Let's say I made a commit on invalid branch A, which was supposed to be made on branch B.
Commit was pushed and I found out about the mistake later.

I know that branch A will be soon merged to B and I want to only revert the commit on A and apply the commit on B.
Branch B will be at some point merged to A, but much later - as for now it's necessary to apply the change only on B.

What is a correct approach here, when I want to avoid another revert on branch B with the merge? You could assume that merge will be conducted by another person, which can easily make a mistake and just apply the revert on B.

Comment: I don't see that happening without commiting the change on B, which you accidentally did on A. How should the merge know not to apply your revert?

Comment: The person doing a merge is in complete control of the result of the merge. If we assume total incompetence on their part, we can make no progress. If we assume total competence, we can have them do anything necessary. You'll need to define, with great precision, the [areas of uncertainty about the competence of the person doing the merge](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/83034-we-demand-rigidly-defined-areas-of-doubt-and-uncertainty).

Comment: It's not about competence. If the person, who done the mistake (PM) does not inform anybody about it, then how can the merger know whether the revert on merge to B is correct or not?
You could even assume that the PM would leave the job in the meantime.
The merger would have no possibility to know without external information.
I would like to find a solution such that the revert would not be automatically applied to B on merge.

Comment: Are force pushes allowed?

Comment: That's a partial circumvent, I would prefer not using them.
You can assume that branches A and B are protected by default and force push would require to contact other people (e.g. manager) with appropriate permissions.
Doing so in each occurrence of such mistake is not really a nice practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some thought, I think I found the solution.
Let's name the invalid commit: `X`

A-commits: `... Ya, X, revert_X, Za, ...`
B-commits: `... Yb, X, Zb, ...`

To avoid applying `revert_X` on `B` one must create a additional PR with commits `revertX` and `X` on branch `B`:

```
git checkout B
git cherry-pick revert_X
git cherry-pick X
```

Now on merge `A -> B` the revert_X is not applied, because it was already made on `B`.

---

**Sample:**

Branch A:
[image: Branch A files]
Branch B:
[image: Branch B files]

And commit history:

[image: commit-history]

Comment: And the commit will be applied again (as intended) on merge `B -> A` in future :)

Comment: @AD7six, the solution assumes that commit X was already applied on B.

Answer (score 4):

There is no magic whereby changes can be removed, merged somewhere else and then appear, accepting this should help understanding the steps required to achieve the desired end state.

Consider the following simplified history, which matches the scenario described in the question:

```
$ git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
* 9eb80d9 (b) Some change added to b only
| * c297cb5 (a) Should be on b, but not a
|/
* 3c5caf4 (main) Initial commit
```

## First, clean up

> I made a commit on invalid branch A, which was supposed to be made on branch B

The following actions will clean up the current situation:

```
$ git switch a
$ git revert HEAD # Revert the mistake
[a 92f9287] Revert "Should be on b, but not a"
```

At this time the effects of 'Should be on b, but not a' are negated on `a` and not present on `b`.

## Second, establish a common history

Avoiding merge problems is all about establishing a common commit history - here that means cherry-picking the problematic commit to `b` *and* reverting it:

```
$ git switch b
$ git cherry-pick 9eb80d9 # Reapply the mistake
$ git revert HEAD # AND revert it
```

That results in:

```
$ git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
* 8d7c582 (b) Revert "Should be on b, but not a"   # Fixing Mistake
* ecf8f7c Should be on b, but not a                # Fixing Mistake
* 9eb80d9 Some change added to b only
| * 3339ef1 (a) Revert "Should be on b, but not a" # Clean up
| * c297cb5 Should be on b, but not a                
|/
* 3c5caf4 (main) Initial commit
```

At this time the effects of 'Should be on b, but not a' are negated in both branches.

## Third, make the change in the right place

So we have a clean slate, all that's necessary now is to reapply the commit to the correct branch:

```
$ git switch b
$ git revert HEAD
```

Resulting in:

```
$ git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
* fb744c1 (b) Revert "Revert "Should be on b, but not a"" # Re-apply
* 8d7c582 Revert "Should be on b, but not a"              # Fixing Mistake
* ecf8f7c Should be on b, but not a                       # Fixing Mistake
* 9eb80d9 Some change added to b only
| * 3339ef1 (a) Revert "Should be on b, but not a"        # Clean Up
| * c297cb5 Should be on b, but not a
|/
* 3c5caf4 (main) Initial commit
```

At this time the effects of 'Should be on b, but not a' are only on branch `b`.

Note: The commit reapplying the change doesn't have to be a revert, could equally be a normal commit.

## Merging, no problem

> Branch B will be at some point merged to A

That's no problem now:

```
$ git switch a
$ git merge b
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
```

With the commits/reverts as described that will apply cleanly resulting in:

```
$ git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
*   bf1ff12 (a) Merge branch 'b' into a
|\
| * fb744c1 (b) Revert "Revert "Should be on b, but not a""
| * 8d7c582 Revert "Should be on b, but not a"
| * ecf8f7c Should be on b, but not a
| * 9eb80d9 Some change added to b only
* | 3339ef1 Revert "Should be on b, but not a"
* | c297cb5 Should be on b, but not a
|/
* 3c5caf4 (main) Initial commit
```

Now the effects of 'Should be on b, but not a' are on branch `a` and `b`.

Comment: I see we have similar answers, but yours is nicely generalised :)  Also thank you for showing me `switch` command - first time I see it :D

Answer (score 0):

**This solution needs the merger to be informed and seems to not be feasible.**

1. Revert the commit on A.
2. Do your commit on B, as you would have liked in the first place.
3. Merge normally (or let the merge be done by that other person)

I'd think that merge should be able to handle that situation, with the result of A not containing the commit, but B containing the commit.

> I know that branch A will be soon merged to B and I want to only
> revert the commit on A and apply the commit on B.

That sounds exactly like what I suggest. Revert on A, commit on B. Merge normally, it will be auto-merged resulting in B keeping the change or it will require manual conflict resolution.

Comment: I see you don't see the problem. When I apply the revert on A then apply commit on B and then merge, the commit will be reverted again on B and it shouldn't.

Comment: @MrPatience Are you sure that's what's going to happen? Was B created from A before or after the incorrect commit?

Comment: @Mr Patience That is up to the merge process - The commit on A will have a different HASH than that on B, thus they are not identical and either can be auto-merged or need conflict-resolution.

Comment: I am asking about a solution, so the other person (merger) doesn't have know about it.
B is a branch with new functionality (feature/sth)
A is master
The functionality should be on master at some point, but let's say in 2 months.
The commit should be on B now and in a week there'll a merge from A to B.